# Email Domain Validation

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am building an internal site for work and I only want users to be able to register with a work email as a safety measure. Below is effectively what I'm looking for, but plugging this in somewhere is pretty hack imo. What is the proper way to go about doing this? I thought Identity's (2.0) UserValidator had a lot more properties but I can only find 2 now..

```
if(Email.Text.Contains("@gmail.com"))
     //register user
```

Comment: I would use [`EndsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131430(v=vs.110).aspx) and make it case insensitive, but if it works, it works.

Comment: I would agree with vcsjones; assuming you only allow access internally, you have certain other levels of protection, but technically there's nothing stopping someone from registering mydomain.com [well, pick one that isn't already taken], setting up DNS MX so that *.mydomain.com goes somewhere useful, and then putting in billgates@gmail.com.mydomain.com.

Comment: true, ends with is a good idea for that reason. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to validate on the front end using a validator control.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator(v=vs.100).aspx